# Want to replace backslash in python3 string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string

```
"abc INC\","None", "0", "test"
```

From this string I want to replace any occurrence of backslash when it appears before " with a pipe |. I wrote the following code but it actually takes out " and leaves the \ behind.

```
import re
str = "\"abc INC\\\",\"None\", \"0\", \"test\""
str = re.sub("(\\\")", "|", str)
print(str)

Output: |abc INC\|,|None|, |0|, |test|
Desired Output: "abc INC|","None", "0", "test"
```

Can someone point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't know python, but you can use this regex `\\(?=")`

Comment: please use `'` to delimite your python string if there are `"` inside, it will be clearer to see what are your strings

Comment: @MosesKoledoye it is a complete string. Read the code which has escape sequence.

Comment: @jotasi here is the output

`|"abc INC\|",|"None|", |"0|", |"test|"`

Comment: @Jacquot

str = '\"abc INC\\\",\"None\", \"0\", \"test\"'

Comment: `str = re.sub("(\\\\\")", "|", str)` works if you really want to do it your way, but the answers below are much nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following *positive lookahead* assertion `'\\(?=")'`:

```
import re

my_str = "\"abc INC\\\",\"None\", \"0\", \"test\""
p = re.sub(r'\\(?=")', '|', my_str)
print(p)
# '"abc INC|","None", "0", "test"'
```

Try not to use builtin names as names for variables, viz. `str`, to avoid shadowing the builtin.

Comment: That did the job. Any good tutorial where I can learn this bad boy?

Comment: @r0xette You can start with the [re docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). It has a lot of useful details with a few examples :))

Answer (score 3):

See Jamie Zawinksi's [famous quote about regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/). Try to only resort to the use of re's when absolutely necessary. In this case, it isn't.

The actual content of string `str` (bad name for a variable, by the way, since there's a built-in type of that name) is

```
"abc INC\","None", "0", "test"
```

Why not just

```
str.replace('\\"', '|"')
```

which will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think about it. And I will keep in mind "Try to only resort to the use of re's when absolutely necessary."

Answer (score 0):

This must solve your problem:

```
import re
s = "\"abc INC\\\",\"None\", \"0\", \"test\""
s = re.sub(r"\\", "|", s)
```

Also don't use str as a variable name, it is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0):

For literal backslashes in python regexes you need to escape  twice, giving you the pattern `'\\\\"'` or `"\\\\\""`. The first escaping is needed for python to actually put a backslash into the string. But regex patterns themself use backshlashes as a special character (for things like `\w` word characters, etc.). The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) states:

> The special sequences consist of '\' and a character from the list below. If the ordinary character is not on the list, then the resulting RE will match the second character.

So the pattern `\"` will match a single `"` because `"` is not a character with a special meaning there.

You can use the raw notation to only escape once: `r'\\"'`.